# System.InvalidCastException when inheriting functions from an Interface from another .cs?

Tags: c#, inheritance, enums, interface

i'm quite new at coding and I was trying to inherit functions from an interface created by another .cs solution, but can't seem to properly inherit it.

***The Interface im trying to inherit the functions from:***

```
public interface Ilocation
{
    public enum Movement {North, South, East, West};

    public int Solution(char directions);
}
```

***The actual solution that I am trying to inherit it to:***

```
namespace Project
{
    public class ProgramA 
    {
        class actualsolution : Ilocation
        {
            int Ilocation.Solution(char directions)
            {
                  //bunch of code
                return (variable);
            }
        }

        static void Main()
        {
            Ilocation obj = new actualsolution();
            // if I use obj.Movement() it does not accept the variable assigned in the method above?
        }
    }
}
```

But whenever I try to do anything with it, it just comes back as `Unable to cast object of type 'Project.ProgramA' to type 'Ilocation'.`??
Please help!

Comment: What is `IMovement`? It seems to be missing from your example. Also `ILocation` doesn't have method `Movement` only an enum. It has `Solution()` method. It seems to be some obvious mistypes in this example.

Comment: @Paweł Łukasik Really sorry, I had to rewrite the question again so a few mistakes slipped in, which I fixed now. The enum `Movement` is a variable that I need to properly implement the `Solution`.

Comment: I have no issue compiling it now. Your error msg is pretty obvious. It would be generate with such line: `Ilocation obj = new ProgramA();` If you really have what's shown in the example this program compiles.

Comment: The problem is that it does compile, but it doesn't return the correct result, which would be `(variable)`, instead it just returns this error message

Comment: The error looks like exception being thrown. Maybe the "bunch of code" is the problem. But without it it's impossible to say.

Answer (score 0):

Movement is defined as a type in your interface and not as a property, this is why you can't assign it anything nor can you invoke it with Movement() since it's not a method. There's no casting operation in what you posted so your other error is from the code that you omitted.